# JavaScript: sort and map array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
const obj = {
  "total": [{
      "name": "asdf",
      "score": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "zxcv",
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "qwer",
      "score": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "poiu",
      "score": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "lkjh",
      "score": 6
    }
  ]
}
// expected
// ["qwer", "asdf", "poiu", "lkjh", "zxcv"]
```

Do you know how to arrange it like this?

The sorting criteria are in the descending order of the "score" value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
  "total": [{
      "name": "asdf",
      "score": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "zxcv",
      "score": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "qwer",
      "score": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "poiu",
      "score": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "lkjh",
      "score": 6
    }
  ]
}

const res = obj["total"].sort((i, j) => j.score - i.score).map((i)=>i.name);
console.log(res);
// expected
// ["qwer", "asdf", "poiu", "lkjh", "zxcv"]
```

Comment: I love you so much.!!!!     :) :) :) <3

Answer (score 1):

`total.sort((a,b) => b.score-a.score).map( x => x.name );`

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort the array according to the `score`
- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), return names of sorted items

```js
const total =  [ { "name": "asdf", "score": 8 }, { "name": "zxcv", "score": 4 }, { "name": "qwer", "score": 17 }, { "name": "poiu", "score": 8 }, { "name": "lkjh", "score": 6 } ];

const sortedNames = total
  .sort(({ score: a }, { score: b }) => b - a)
  .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(sortedNames);
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU !!!!!!!!! <3 <3 and thank you

Comment: You could have marked this as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: Thanks to your incredibly cool code,,,,,,,,, I succeeded!!!!